# Proxy config after importing configuration (Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins

I have restored config in Jenkins using ThinBackup plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/thinBackup)

Intermittently proxy stops working after restarts and I get this warning in logs:

```
Jul 23, 2014 11:02:04 AM hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor getTestForReverseProxySetup
WARNING: http://hostBB.com:8080/manage vs. http://hostAA.com:8080/manage
```

`hostBB` is where I imported the full backup made on `hostAA`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I am experiencing this as well, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @no for special reasons I cannot even file a bug, pls do that if you can and paste link to bugrep here so I can track it as well

Comment: I made a change to my config file that may help.  What are you using to proxy?